# HTTP Status 500 - Expected session attribute 'consent'

Tags: spring-mvc

this is my html form of consents. after posting the inputs i get error on the browser

```
<form th:object="${consent}" action="../users/userDetails.html" th:action="@{${#httpServletRequest.servletPath}}" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
    <label for="last_name">Service  Provider</label>
        <select id="provider" name="provider" class="form-control" th:onchange="'javascript:showPIIDoc(this.value);'">
            <option th:value="0" >Select a Service Provider</option>
            <option th:each="provider : ${user.providers}"  name="name"  th:value="${user.id} +','+ ${provider.id}" th:text="${provider.name}" >[name]</option>
        </select>

    </div>  
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
    <label for="last_name">PII Document</label>
        <select id ="documentdiv"  class="form-control">

        </select>
    </div>  
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
    <label for="last_name">Share with</label>
        <select  class="form-control">
            <option th:value="0" >Select a user you want share the document to</option>
            <option  name="name" th:each="user : ${users}"  th:value="${user.id}" th:text="${user.firstName} + ' ' + ${user.lastName}">[name]</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
        <label for="last_name">Consent</label>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="share" th:value="1" th:text="Share" />
     </div> 

     <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <div style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px" class="form-actions">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Consent</button>

    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

this is my controller

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}/providers/{providerId}/documents/{documentId}/consents/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String processNewConsentForm(@PathVariable("userId") int userId, @PathVariable("providerId") int providerId, 
                @PathVariable("documentId") int documentId, @ModelAttribute("consent") Consent consent, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
            User user = this.clinicService.findUserById(userId);
            Provider provider = this.clinicService.findProviderById(providerId);
            System.out.println("daghade");
            System.out.println(provider);
            Document doc = this.clinicService.findDocumentById(userId);

            Consent c =new Consent();
                c.setProvider(provider);
                c.setDocument(doc);
                c.setUser(user);
                c.setStatus(c.getStatus());
                c.setFriend(c.getFriend());

                System.out.println(c);

            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "providers/createOrUpdateConsentForm";
            } else {
                this.clinicService.saveConsent(c);
                status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:/users/{userId}";
        }

        }
```

I get this error on the browser

> HTTP Status 500 - Expected session attribute 'consent'

after submitting the form

This is the code of Controller for GET Method. it used to call the consent form

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}/providers/{providerId}/documents/{documentId}/consents/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initNewConsentForm(@PathVariable("userId") int userId,@PathVariable("providerId") int providerId,@PathVariable("documentId") int documentId, Model model) {
        User user = this.clinicService.findUserById(userId);
        Provider provider = this.clinicService.findProviderById(providerId);
        Document document = this.clinicService.findDocumentById(documentId);
        Collection<User> users = this.clinicService.AllUsers();

        Consent consent = new Consent();
            model.addAttribute("provider",provider);
            model.addAttribute("document", document);
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            model.addAttribute("users", users);
            return "providers/createOrUpdateConsentForm";

    }
```

Comment: why you have attributes `action` and `th:action` in your form?

Comment: I am using thymeleaf. we can use both attributes. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: i know that is thymeleaf, try to remove the `action` attribute

Comment: It didnt work same problem. Where do you think this error is located? in the controller or  html? @NikolayRusev

Comment: the problem may be is located in the method where you are serving this form. can you post your code for the GET method. May be you are missing `model.addAttribute("consent", new Consent());`

Comment: This is the code for the GET method:

Comment: please edit your question with the GET method. You can't post long content in your comments.

Comment: Thank you so much!! stay blessed! @NikolayRusev

Comment: for nothing. II'm glad to help you

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "user.providers" (providers/createOrUpdateConsentForm:248)

Comment: @NikolayRusev M passing two value in the th:value is it the reason for the error in the top comment?

Comment: may be not, but please open a new stack overflow thread and will look into that, because they are separate problems. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add  `model.addAttribute("consent", consent);` in your GET method.